# Having a List as an element in the list Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Given a list (List1), I am trying to square each number in the list and return the answers in a new list (List2), where each element in List2 is in the form (Xi, Ji).

```
?- square([1,2,3,], L).
L = [[1,1],[2,4],[3,9]].
```

This is my code:

```
square([], []).
square([N|Tail], [SqrdN|SqrdTail]) :-
    SqrdN is [N|N*N],
    square(Tail, SqrdTail).
```

This is giving me a type error: '[]' expected, found `[1|1*1]' (a compound) ("x" must hold one character).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing your output representation (lists of `[Item, SquaredItem]`) with the computation of the squares, and your output term is also not a proper list of two items.

Using library clpfd:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
square([], []).
square([N|Tail], [[N, SqrdN]|SqrdTail]) :-
    SqrdN #= N*N,
    square(Tail, SqrdTail).
```

or without clpfd:

```
square([], []).
square([N|Tail], [[N, SqrdN]|SqrdTail]) :-
    SqrdN is N*N,
    square(Tail, SqrdTail).
```